# NPE running a JSF application as a Swarm uberjar

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-swarm

Running Wildfly Swarm with a JSF application results in this NPE:

```
2016-03-13 08:08:07,370 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putAll(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1084)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl.<init>(ServletContextImpl.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:150)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
```

How can I fix this

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that including the JSF fraction without the Weld fraction causes the NPE. You need the following:

```
compile 'org.wildfly.swarm:jsf:1.0.0.Beta2'
compile 'org.wildfly.swarm:weld:1.0.0.Beta2'
```